# Free OpenGL-accelerated GNUPlot-like tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, gnuplot

I am using GNUplot to plot large volumes of data that I want to visualize in 3D - e.g., using the pm3d option. This is very slow rendering in software - is there free software that will do this using OpenGL or something?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that. But your favorite language + OpenGL could do any kind of simple line/dot plotting very easily.

Comment: You could try VTK http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK_FAQ#Mac_OS_X.

Answer (score 1):

[ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) will do this.

This beast is one of the major analysis and visualization tools used in the nuclear and particle physics communities these days. It can move a lot of data fast, and has fairly  sophisticated set of visualization tools, and supports OpenGL. You can do the work in compiled c++ code, in the cint interpreter, or using the python bindings.

The big downside is that you may have to read a lot of documentation before you're ready to begin.

Comment: There is a reason that ROOT is not really used outside of the nuclear & particle physics world(s). Avalys, feel free to try out ROOT but I'll warn you, it will probably be a nightmare for you. It's bad enough to attempt using ROOT in Linux; I can only imagine it's even worse in OS X which has all sorts of other quirks (like not having a Fortran compiler - I know ROOT relies heavily on Fortran).

Comment: ROOT *does not* rely on fortran. You may be thinking of CERNLIB. Installation by hand is a bear, but totally unnecessary in most cases: fink has a ROOT package. I'd have recommended trying lighter weight suggestions first, only there don't seem to be any...